¿Cómo puedo pasar 2 parametros en un viewbag?
Tengo este ViewBag
ViewData["IdCliente"] = new SelectList(_context.Cliente, "IdCliente", "Nombre", pedido.IdCliente);

Lo que pasa es que en la Select list me gustaría que se mostrase no solo el Nombre del cliente, sino, el id y el nombre por ejemplo '701-Juan'
Un ejemplo de como me gustaría implementarlo pero está mal
ViewData["IdCliente"] = new SelectList(_context.Cliente, "IdCliente", "IdCliente-Nombre", pedido.IdCliente);


A la clase cliente le creas una propiedad que los una
